# about gz file as input for hadoop mapreduce job's input

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing mapreduce that take gz files as input.
Some of the gz files are actually corrupted. But the mapper didn't notice that and finished the job successfully.
May I ask how hadoop process this kind of files?
We cannot open an error gz file from command line using gunzip.
Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop transfers the gz file to the node the mapper is executing on; uncompresses the file  then iterates over the contents. Each file will be operated on by a single mapper.

If the file is corrupt, it's possible that the mapper never actually executes the mapper (or just the map function. If we assume the mapper get's launched; Hadoop attempts to unzip the file; fails silently and continues onto the mapper with an empty file for the input. The contents of the "unzipped file" is empty, which allows the mapper to complete successfully.

You may need some code in the `setup` and `cleanup` functions that would allow you to detect an 'empty' file so you can increase a counter saying the job didn't actually process any data.